# Problems with catkin with ros noetic

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I updated ubuntu from 18.04 version to 20.04 version and consequently I installed ros noetic.

The problem is: I must install some files running a .sh file, one of these files is python-catkin-tools, but I read that ros noetic doesn't work with python 2, so in the .sh file I changed that line with python3-catkin-tools, but when the script is running, it stops with this error:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'osrf-pycommon>0.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by catkin-tools.
```

If it can help you with the answer, the last line of .sh file is "catkin build"

Is there a fix with which I can avoid this error? Or I must reinstall ubuntu 18.04 with ros melodic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355478/problems-with-catkin-with-ros-noetic/) by [Davide_970](https://answers.ros.org/users/55962/davide_970/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2020-06-21

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davide_970](https://answers.ros.org/users/55962/davide_970/) on 2020-06-22**:
Thanks I'll try

**Comment by [Davide_970](https://answers.ros.org/users/55962/davide_970/) on 2020-06-22**:
Ok I installed catkin_tools with

```
with pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git
```

But now the error is:

```
catkin: command not found
```

I also tried with "catkin_make" instead "catkin build", but it's the same problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-22**:
Try opening a new shell/terminal.

Note: this is no longer really a ROS/Catkin problem, as installing packages using `pip` into your `$HOME` with `--user` is normal practice with `pip`.

**Comment by [Davide_970](https://answers.ros.org/users/55962/davide_970/) on 2020-06-22**:
I tried with a new terminal but it's the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [catkin/catkin_tools#594](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/594). This is a known issue.

And see #q353113 for a work-around (note: this is really a work-around, *not* a fix).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This suggestion solved the issue for me: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/594#issuecomment-651938327

I installed python3-catkin-tools and then :

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-lint python3-pip
pip3 install osrf-pycommon
```

---

Originally posted by [azazdeaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/35111/azazdeaz/) with karma: 121 on 2020-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [onlynithin](https://answers.ros.org/users/73978/onlynithin/) on 2021-05-01**:
This worked for me! Thanks a ton !

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:
This answer is popular, as we can see from the upvotes, but for future readers: please be aware that installing system dependencies using `pip3` is not recommended on systems with package managers (such as Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, etc).

An immediate disadvantage is that you won't be notified of updates. This will easily create situations where your `pip3` installed version of `osrf-pycommon` starts to get out-of-date and (for instance) `catkin_tools` becoming incompatible with it. ROS Answers is full of Q&As which deal with the fall-out of people using `pip` to install such dependencies.

The `apt` version, which you can install just as easily, see #q353113, does not have that problem.